# Will a RF IC transmitter work without any antenna?

Tags: rf, antenna, transmitter

The IC is this one - https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/Si4012.pdf

It seems i have set it up correctly according to its I2C dialog with the MCU, but nothing gets received by my SDR.

P.S. @downvoters: why the hate ?
Got an answer for the hate, and more hate, excellent!

Surely enough I've spent some hours on the internet trying to figure whether these things can work without any antenna or not. Obviously with no luck. And no, the pdf linked here does not clearly make it obvious to everyone that the damn antenna can not be skipped. Actually there are a some separate pdf files describing how to make the trace antenna for this chip. I guess everybody knows, sure. Here is another link with me asking in their forums yesterday - https://community.silabs.com/t5/Proprietary/Si4012-with-chip-antenna/m-p/195937/highlight/true#M2987

Anyway, short and to the point post, maybe from a phone while in the subway ? Nah, hating is more fun.

Comment: You could connect the transmitter directly to the receiver with a cable. But the chip by itself won't radiate any significant energy.

Comment: Downvoting criteria is meant to be "does not show research effort or is unclear ir unuseful". Downvoting is usually but not always nit due to hate (it happens) but due to socially maladapted people who do not understand the meaning of the criteria description. || See p8 in data sheet fro basic antenna configuration. Not very demanding.

Comment: How about handing a 75 ohm resistor (perhaps DC_blocked with 100F) on that TX output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You really can't cheat physics.

Note that some devices can even be damaged when not attaching a TX antenna, since power has nowhere to go (this is likely not the case here).

Your unconnected TXP and TXM pins will act as very very bad antennas, and might thus actually might cause problems with the rest of your system.

Really, it's not absolutely clear to me how you came to the conclusion that a radio transmitter without an antenna might be a good idea!

Comment: Ah... well then... :) I am just nooby to RF and I've used one other transmitter without any antenna or problem. But, I now realize it seats on its PCB; a tiny one, but still a PCB!

Comment: @kellogs I might not recognized the antenna on the PCB..